# SQL Statement as parameters

Tags: sql

Is it possible to do something like that in SQL?

```
DECLARE @t Nvarchar(50)

SET @t = 'SELECT * FROM KIN_PHON'

execute @t  --??
```

Comment: You *can* - but I would advise **against** doing something like this.... it's called *dynamic SQL* and can be a godsend in *some cases* - but totally unnecessary and pure overhead in other cases. Don't just get in the habit of doing everything like this - bad for performance, horrible for security....

Answer (score 1):

Use `exec`:

```
DECLARE @t Nvarchar(50)
SET @t = 'SELECT * FROM KIN_PHON'
exec (@t)
```

Or with parameters, `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from YourTable where ID = @ID'
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@ID int', @ID = 42;
```